# .Net core web apps not running on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to publishing .net core applications to Azure for hosting and every time I publish my project using Visual Studio I am loading into a `502.5` error.

My steps:

1. Launch VS 2017 (v15.4.4) as admin
2. Create new .Net core web application, .Net framework 4.7, .Net core 2.0, any of the project templates, it doesn't seem to matter.
3. Publish to a new app service, configuring it all, inside the free tier web hosting.
4. Publish completes and loads into website with a `502.5` error.

Is there something I need to do in the `Program.cs` file that sets up the starting code? Every thing I have seen online says that you can just create a new project and instantly publish it.

Comment: Did you previously publish the app with another version of .net core? 
Check this question for a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550096/asp-net-core-2-0-on-azure-results-in-a-502-5

Comment: Nope, this is a new web app, this is brand new project.